# Differenciate between import statements

Tags: python, python-import

I have a requirement to differentiate between the following import techniques from within `mylibrary`:

`import mylibrary`

and

`from mylibrary import abc`

The reason I need to do this is my library is used by a 3rd party tool (lets call it `othertool`) which only does `import mylibrary`. This will then run some code specific to `othertool` (setting up the environment specific to `othertool`)

`mylibrary` can of course also be used as a library, and so I dont want the code specific to `othertool` being run when it is used like `from mylibrary import abc`.

I have tried things like the following, but can't find anything to differentiate between the two import techniques.

```py
import sys
binary_names = ['othertool', 'othertool.py']
if any(bn in arg for bn in binary_names for arg in sys.argv):
    from mylibrary import main_othertool
```

But this would require modification if `othertool` changed it's name.

Any suggestions? TIA!

Comment: It sounds to me like `othertool` should be doing that setup, rather than baking compatibility for `othertool` into `mylibrary`?

Comment: Not possible.  There is no difference between the two forms of `import` until *after* the module has been completely executed.

Comment: Thanks both - @AriCooper-Davis "othertool" isn't under my control and I need a way to distinguish between it doing "import mylibrary" (which is it's only entry point) and someone using "mylibrary" as a library importing it however they want to

Comment: @jasonharper - would you be able to share how you could distinguish this _after_ it has been loaded?

Comment: There is no difference at all in the imported library itself.  The only difference is what names were added to the namespace of the importing script.